# Rails show banner from product vendor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I have a site that has a product that belongs_to a vendor. on the product show page I would like to display a banner that also belongs to this vendor. Currently I am showing a random banner from any vendor, how do I isolate this to the same vendor as the product.

my models

```
class Banner < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vendor
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: { normal: 0, featured: 1 }
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  is_impressionable counter_cache: true, :column_name => :views
  searchkick
  acts_as_taggable

  has_many :likes
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :collects
  has_many :banners, :through => :vendor

end

class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  has_many :products
  has_many :brands
  has_many :promotions
  has_many :banners
end
```

the show in products controller

```
def show
    @meta_title = meta_title @product.name
    @og_properties = {
        title: @meta_title,
        type:  'website',
        image: view_context.image_url(@product.image),  
        url: product_path,
        locale: 'en_AU',
        description: @product.description.html_safe,
    }
    @similar_products = Product.order("RANDOM()").first(4)
    @collection = Collection.all
    @product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id])
    impressionist(@product)
    @banner = Banner.order("RANDOM()").first
  end
```

I am currently calling this on the show.html.erb page

```
<%= raw(@banner.trackingcode) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an amount of brands per particular vendor is not very huge, this would perfectly suit your needs:

```
@banner = @product.vendor.banners.to_a.sample
```

or:

```
@banner = @product.vendor.banners.order("RANDOM()").limit(1).first
```

Comment: thanks @mudasobwa your answer would have also worked :)

Comment: The difference between this answer and the selected one is that mine returns a random value, as you asked, while the selected one always returns a first one, which is not what you wanted.

Comment: yes true. is it better to call .to_a instead of .order("RANDOM()"). and why?

Comment: No it’s not, just a matter of habit: on small lists `to_a` works always and `.order("RANDOM()")` only for RDBMS that support ordering by random (e.g. will fail for `Cassandra` and/or `RethinkDB` databases.)